# How can i determain if date is between two dates in Scala

Tags: scala, date

How can I get date between two dates ?

This is my date:

```
val date = "01 Jan, 2015"
```

Date range:

```
val dateFrom = "01 Jan, 1970"
val dateTill = "01 Jan, 2016"
```

I want to check is my date is between date range.

This is what i have try:

```
def getLocalDate(date: String): LocalDate = {

  LocalDate.parse(date, format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM, yyyy"))
}

def isDateBetWeenRange(from: String, till: String, date: String): Boolean = {

  val fromDate = getLocalDate(from)
  val tillDate = getLocalDate(till)
  val myDate = getLocalDate(date)

  myDate.isBefore(tillDate) && myDate.isAfter(fromDate) 
}
```

But is case the date is same as till date this return false:

```
val date = "01 Jan, 2010"
println(isDateBetWeenRange("01 Jan, 2000", "01 Jan, 2016", "01 Jan, date))
```

Comment: If you want inclusive range, replace `x isBefore y` with `!(x isAfter y)` and similarly for the other condition.

Answer (score 0):

Well the nice and Scala way to add some behavior would be to add an implicit class for `LocalDate`

**For example:**

```
implicit class SLocalDate(val time: LocalDate) {
  def isBeforeEq(other: ChronoLocalDate) = !time.isAfter(other)
  def isAfterEq(other: ChronoLocalDate) = !time.isBefore(other)
}
```

Now, in the scope of this implicit you could change your test to:

```
myDate.isBeforeEq(tillDate) && myDate.isAfterEq(fromDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust your function:

```
(myDate.isBefore(tillDate) && myDate.isAfter(fromDate)) || 
  myDate.isEqual(tillDate) || 
  myDate.isEqual(fromDate)
```